# Wait for click to execute Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, chess

im doing a chess game, and when i select a piece it show me possible squares to move it, i need the code to stop here until the user click the new position.

```
$('td').click(function(){
    //Show posibilities

    $('td').click(function(){ //i need to stop here until user click again
        //choose new position and move the piece
    }

}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I'd make the inner .cick only apply to possible moves - personally, I'd use drag'n'drop as it closely resembles how real world chess is played

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to stop the code for that. When user clicks the piece it shows the possibilities and when user clicks one of the possible moves it moves. Or if clicks again on the same piece it removes posibilities. Basically it's like this;

```
    $('piece').click(function(){
        if(!showed) {
        //Show posibilities
        }else{
        //Remove posibilities
        }

    }
    $('possibilities').click(function(){
        //choose new position and move the piece

    }
```